# Gitlab runner CI is testing node_modules

Tags: angular, gitlab, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular 8 application that is adding some dependencies.

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --open --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0",
    "test": "ng test --watch",
    "test-ui": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI",
    "test:coverage": "ng test --watch=true --code-coverage=true",
    "build:dev": "ng build --progress --output-path ../public",
    "build:prod": "ng build --progress --prod --output-path ../public"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.137",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "ngx-audio-player": "^9.0.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

I'm running it into a Gitlab Runner:

```
image: java:11

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build_stage:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - aws
  - endiag
  - persistent
  script:
  - sbt compile

pages:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
  tags:
  - aws
  - endiag
  - persistent
  script:
  - sbt clean coverage test coverageReport
  - sbt coverageAggregate
  - sbt makeSite
  - mkdir public/scoverage-report
  - mv target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/* public/scoverage-report
  - mkdir public/test-reports
  - mv target/test-reports/* public/test-reports
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
  - pages
  tags:
  - aws
  - endiag
  - persistent
  script:
  - sbt debian:packageBin
  - mkdir debian
  - mv target/1.0-SNAPSHOT_all.deb debian
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - docker
      - doc
      - debian
```

In the test stage I'm getting that error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-audio-player/lib/component/base/base-audio-player.component.d.ts(16,9)
```

I tried to exclude the node_modules on the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

But It's still testing the dependencies on node_modules.

I tried to search for the solution, but I don't found it
How I can solve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the dependency version fixed the problem.
Changing this:

```
 "ngx-audio-player": "^9.0.7",
```

To:

```
 "ngx-audio-player": "9.0.7",
```

Solved my problem.